# Get JSON value from NSDictionary and place in NSString not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

In my previous app I had this code to extract JSON from an NSDictionary variable into a string:

```
NSString *task_id = [jsonString objectForKey:@"key"];
```

It worked very well but for some reason it won't work in my new app anymore? Instead I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d7bda0
```

Does anyone know why this might not work?

Peter

Comment: It seems like your jsonString is, indeed, a String and not a Dictionary.

Comment: 1) NSLog the JSON before you decode it. (Do `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataObjwect encoding:NSUTF8Encoding]` to make an NSData printable.) 2) NSLog the result from the decoding. Observe that a dictionary is surrounded with `{}` and an array with `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the jsonString is `NSDictionary`:

```
if([jsonString isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSString *task_id = [jsonString objectForKey:@"key"];
} else {
    // is not a dictionary
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
}
```

Comment: It is not a dictionary, I will go back to the drawing board and find out why. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: yep, drawing board is the best option :)

Comment: UPDATE: if([jsonString isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary Class]]) { didn't work, but changing the code from 'Class' to 'class' worked great :)